# Convert string to IP range array

Tags: bash, shell, networking

How to convert string `192.168.1.{10..12}` in to array of IPs with range?
It's working when adding IPs in format `192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12` but not if you add range.

This examples as string also not working:
`192.168.1.{10..12}` and this `192.168.{1..3}.{10..12}`

**Here is the code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
iprange="";
tout="";

# Dialog for entering IP range and ping timeout
dialog --colors --ok-label "Submit" \
--backtitle "Scan IP range and request timeout" \
--title "\Zb Scan range \Zn" \
--form "Set scan IP range & request timeout\n \
       \n\Zb------------------ Example ------------------ \
       \nIP range:       192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 \
       \nIP range:       192.168.1.{10..255} \
       \nTimeout (sec):  0.1 or 1\Zn" 15 50 0 \
       "IP range:"      1 1 "$iprange"  1 15 40 0 \
       "Timeout (sec):" 2 1 "$tout"     2 15 3 0 > file.tmp \
       2>&1 >/dev/tty;

# Start retrieving each line from temp file 1 by 1 with sed and declare variables as inputs
iprange=$(sed -n 1p file.tmp)
tout=$(sed -n 2p file.tmp)

# remove temporary file created
rm -f file.tmp

# NOT WORKING if you enter in iprange 192.168.1.{10..12}
# WORKING if you enter in iprange 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11 etc.
echo ${iprange[@]}

ips=($iprange)

echo "Scanning for devices...";
for ip in ${ips[@]}
    do
        echo "-------------------------";
        echo "$ip";
        gtimeout $tout ping "$ip"; # use timeout for linux
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

iprange=$(head -n1 file.tmp)
if [[ $iprange = *[^0-9.{}[:blank:]]* ]]; then
    echo 'Invalid IP range' >&2
    exit 1
fi

eval "ips=($iprange)"
for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
    echo "$ip"
    # do stuff with $ip
done
```

Comment: Now it works for example `192.168.{1..2}.{1..3}` and also works for `192.168.1.{1..3}` but it do not work when you add unique IPs separated by space. Example: `192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4`

Comment: @SashaMilic It should work now.

Comment: Work perfectly..!!!! You are the best..!!!! Thank you very much...